# How to add Alertify js with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, js-css

I want to show messages using **Alertify JS.**
I included **alertify.min.js** and **alertify.css**. But it is not working.

Please anybody can navigate that **how can i use Alertify JS in Magento 1.9**.
Or have any module for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Actually there was issue with JS file placement.

`JS` file should be after `noconflict.js` file.

Thank you